# Set Default Value for Multiple Selection Semantic UI Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I believe there is an answer to my question. I do exactly like some solution I found, but still I can't set default value to my dropdown. Here is my code.

```
<td>                                    
<div ng-controller="daftarGroup" class="ui fluid multiple selection dropdown">
    <input name="group" value="admin" type="hidden">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Group</div>
    <div class="menu">
    <div ng-repeat="y in groups" class="item" data-value="{{ y.gid }}">
        {{ y.gid }}
    </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    </script>
</div>
</td>
```

My dropdown will have a list of group, one of the item is "admin". The data is presented using Angular. Everytime I load the page, I want the dropdown show "admin" as default value. On another fiddle, it run perfectly, but not in my machine. Every time I refresh the page, no value set on my dropdown, but the list of group is accessible. Any idea about my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-ng-options and ng-init with ng-model to have a default value.

HTML:

```
 <select 
         ng-init="group = groups[0]"
         ng-model="group"
         data-ng-options="y.gid for y in groups">
 </select>
```

Angular controller:

```
$scope.groups = [
        {gid: 1},
        {gid: 2}
];
```

Comment: Hai, thank for your fast response. But I use `<div>` to create dropdown, not `<select>` tag. Is it still possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how $(...).dropdown() works, but you could try to add ng-model="selectedGroup" and ng-init="selectedGroup = groups[0];" to the div with the ng-repeat

Comment: I add ng-init and ng-model but nothing change. @Passersby